# Symfony2 Doctrine ORM cascade detach not working

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have Two classes linked together by a ORM OneToMany Relationship

What I want to achieve is that: when I delete a document, the MeasurementData
entities are not removed from the database.

I've tried setting an annotation: @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")

but still it doesn't work. Does anyone know a proper solution to this badly documented
feature in Symfony2 / Doctrine ORM

```
class Document
{
    .....

    /**
     * Measurement Data
     * 
     * @var type 
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MeasurementData", mappedBy="document", cascade={"detach"})
     */
    protected $measurementData;

    .....

}


class MeasurementData
{
    .....

    /**
     * Document
     *
     * @var \Entity\Document 
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Document", inversedBy="measurementData")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="documentId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $document;

    .....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I still can't get the annotations to work properly
I've read the documentation a couple of times already but I've come up with
this easy sollution for now (in my document Controller on the delete Action)
Maybe there is no way though annotations, it sure would've been nice though.

```
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    ...

    $measurements = $em->getRepository('ChemRadeBundle:MeasurementData')->findBy(array(
        'document' => $document
    ));

    foreach ($measurements as $measurement) {
        $measurement->setDocument(null);
        $em->persist($measurement);
    }

    $em->remove($document);
    $em->flush();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `detach` operation is used when you want the EntityManager to stop managing it, but "detach" is not the same as "remove". Use `cascade={"remove"}` and take a look to the ["Working with associations"](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) section in the docs.

```
class Document
{
    .....

    /**
     * Measurement Data
     * 
     * @var type 
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MeasurementData", mappedBy="document", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $measurementData;

    .....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What [Falc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1637446/falc) says into is answer his true but you can still use `onDelete="CASCADE"` annotation (them are "equivalent" in a sort of way; read below)

The main difference between `onDelete="CASCADE"` and `cascade={"remove"}` is that the first is used by doctrine to use cascading mechanism of DBMS (so DBMS will be responsible for deleting operation) whereas the latter is used by doctrine itself (so "application level") to do some `explicit` delete queries.

In your case, as far as we can know from your example, `onDelete="CASCADE"` wasn't working as you probably forgot to update the schema with `php app/consolle doctrine:schema:update --force` CLI command.